# Codeigniter session lost

Tags: codeigniter, session

I use codeigniter for a project, my session is configured to use the mysql database :

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration']      = 7200;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = FALSE;
$config['sess_use_database']    = TRUE;
$config['sess_table_name']      = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']        = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 300;
```

In my controller i have a code like this :

```
$params = array(
        "type"      => $data['activite_name'],
        "activite"  => $data['activite'],
        "nom"       => $data['name'],
        "prenom"    => $data['fname'],
        "tel"       => $data['tel'],
        "email"     => $data['email'],
        "adresse"   => $data['adr'],
        "cp"        => $data['cp'],
        "ville"     => $data['ville']
    );
....
#Load session library and save $params as session
$this->load->library('session');
$this->session->set_userdata($params);

#Test session
$sess_name = $this->session->userdata('name');
echo $sess_name;

#Load view
$this->load->view("templates/header_interne", $data);
$this->load->view("pages/payment_view", $data);
$this->load->view("templates/footer", $data);
```

So when payment_view is loaded i can see my $sess_name value, but when i refresh the page i lost this session, and so on for all my sessions.

Anyone has an idea please?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried auto-loading the session Library?

Comment: Hello Craig, yes i autoloaded it :
    $autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'session');
But it not working.